# Get line number of executing code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do we get the Line number of the currently executing code in C#/WinForms.

In PHP we can do `__LINE__` or `__FUNCTION__` to access details about the currently executing piece of code.

Comment: [this is the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) that refers to what the answer in the question Selman posted is talking about which is what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks this is all very useful. Now I can provide more info and callstack data in my app :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this class and example [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx)

```
StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(i);
Console.WriteLine(" File: {0}", sf.GetFileName());
Console.WriteLine(" Line Number: {0}", sf.GetFileLineNumber());
Console.WriteLine(" Column Number: {0}", sf.GetFileColumnNumber());
```

Comment: Why was this voted down ? It looks like what Im after ?

Comment: OK, NP.  Well if @JTL can provide a code sample ill mark this as answered

Comment: I got your point thx :)